# Javascript Toggle Small Issue

Tags: jquery, toggle

So for this script I found, I'm trying to tailor it to my needs.

I am using this as my html:

```
<a>What is anewall?</a>
<p class="toggle">anewall reponsitionable matte fabric is made from a 7mm polyester fabric      with an acrylic, removable, pressure sensitive adhesive. This adhesive fabric provides as an excellent material for removing, repositioning, and reusing graphics on most wall surfaces. This adhesive fabric shows off an impressive texture, showing quality, while at the same time maintaining the functional removability feature. Keep the adhesive backing free of dust, fibers, and dirt to extent the life span of this product.</p>
```

And using this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Andy Langton's show/hide/mini-accordion - updated 23/11/2009
// Latest version @ http://andylangton.co.uk/jquery-show-hide

// this tells jquery to run the function below once the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

// choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
var showText='Show';
var hideText='Hide';

// initialise the visibility check
var is_visible = false;

// append show/hide links to the element directly preceding the element with a class of      "toggle"
$('.toggle').prev().append(' (<a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>)<br />');

// hide all of the elements with a class of 'toggle'
$('.toggle').hide();

// capture clicks on the toggle links
$('a.toggleLink').click(function() {

// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;

// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);

// toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
//$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
$(this).parent().next('.toggle').toggle('slow');

// return false so any link destination is not followed
return false;

});
});
</script>
```

It works on jsFiddle as seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/nfCCh/

But these large blocks of text on my site almost 'hiccup' per say.

This can be seen here using the username "stack" and password "overflow" here.

http://anewall.com/content/11-faq

I would really appreciate some help, as I am a bit, well, a huge jQuery newb. :)

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your issue simply by applying a fixed width to your paragraphs, rather than relying on `div.justifiedcustom` to constrain the proportions. The JS/jQuery should then be able to  better calculate and synchronise the revealing process.

The 'hiccup' is actually the paragraph expanding until it can't get any wider and then suddenly showing you the remaining content. The same 'hiccup' can be replicated in your fiddle just by adding a containing `div` the same way you have in your main demo. http://jsfiddle.net/nfCCh/1/

Comment: Thanks tw16! That worked perfectly. :) One more question if you don't mind, do you know if it is possible to make the text in the <a></a> tags act as the link instead of the "Show" and "Hide" text showing up?